# Formatting questions in `jss_article()` of **rticles** package

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am preparing my manuscript based on the JSS Template in R Studio. Indirectly, I am using `jss_article()` from the **rticles** package. Now, following the instructions for journal submission, I got my article ready by using precise LaTex commands.

However, I ran into the following formatting questions.

[ ] I would like `jss_article()` to execute inline code commands like `r print(x)`. Left unaltered, it fails to compile as in [Rmarkdown error #385 (along with others)](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385). Following the solution, I put dollar signs around it.  However, the inline code was not executed but printed to the screen. In the JSS format, are inline commands not executed in `rticles::jss_article()`? 
[ ] Frequently, I would like to use inline code to extract an element from a list, like `r print(x$B)`. Since "$" is a LaTex symbol, I need to use "\".  Executing $`r print(x\$B)`$ leads to
 [image]

[ ] Long names run off the page like `# Example 4: Interval-Censored data with univariate Bayesian multivariate imputation .` The use of `tidy` and `tidy.opts` options of **knitr** seems to be ignored in the JSS Template.

[ ] The knitr::kable() capability does not seem to be supported in `jss_article()`. Can you recommended a function to construct publication-worthy tables (similar to the output from `kable()`)?

The RStudio Template was edited to reflect these issues:

````
---
documentclass: jss
author:
  - name: FirstName LastName
    affiliation: University/Company
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: \email{name@company.com}
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: Second Author
    affiliation: Affiliation
title:
  formatted: "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \\pkg{foo}"
  # If you use tex in the formatted title, also supply version without
  plain:     "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo"
  # For running headers, if needed
  short:     "\\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title"
abstract: >
  The abstract of the article.
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keywords, not capitalized, "\\proglang{Java}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Java]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
output: rticles::jss_article
---

#Issues here
[ ] It seems that inline R code does not run. As mentioned in rmardown error#385, I need to put dollar signs around it.  <!--  $ r print(x)$  --> Is this the case.
[ ] If I want to use inline R code while picking an element from the list I'll need to use the "$" sign. However, it is a special character; do I hit escape?
[ ] Long names run off the page, like `# Example 4: Interval-Censored data with univariate Bayesian multivariate imputation .`
[ ] `knitr::kable()` does not seem to be supported. Can you recommend a function that provides publication-worthy tables using `jss_article()`? 

# Example 4: Interval-Censored data with univariate Bayesian multivariate imputation  

This template demonstrates some of the basic latex you'll need to know to create a JSS article.

```{r echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = "styler",
                      tidy.opts = list(blank = FALSE, width.cutoff = 40)
)
                      # options for tidy to remove blank lines [blank = FALSE] and set the approximate line width to be 80.
```

# R code
Can be inserted in regular R markdown blocks.

```{r}
x <- as.list(1:10)
names(x) <- LETTERS[1:10]
x$A
```

blah blah blah $`r print(x)`.$ I want 2 here.
and <!--$ r print(x). $  I want to print element B of x, or 2. -->

```{r}
l <- list(x = x, a = letters)

fit <- lm(y~x, data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)))

knitr::kable( summary(fit)$coefficients ) 
#              label = "bootWQS", 
 #             digits = 3, caption = "WQS estimates using bootstrap multiple imputation. Summary of statistics after performing WQS regression across two datasets. " ) 
```

# Computational Details
Using Github versions of **rticles** package had the same result.

```{r, echo =FALSE}
xfun::session_info('rticles')
```
````

[image: Knitting the document yields the following output.]

[image]

Comment: For the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xiangyun Huang, an author of **rticles**, solved these questions by:

- using [the **booktabs** LaTex package and the `booktabs::pdf_book()` output option](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latexpdf.html).
- setting the `tidy` option to `"formatR"` and  not "`styler`".

Further notes on the questions:

- To execute the inline R code, do NOT use dollar signs and use the regular `r ...` syntax.
- Long titles for the primary header `#` still run off the page.  The behavior is defined by the journal document class (`jss.cls`). The easiest solution: avoid using too long first-level headers.
- Long secondary headers `##` remain on the line and does not run off the page, thanks to **booktabs** package.
- To make pretty tables, still use `kable()` but add the `format` and `booktabs` arguments:

```
knitr::kable(summary(fit)$coefficients, digits = 3, 
label = "demo-table" caption = " A CAPTION HERE ", 
format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE
)
```

[See the cross-post for more information.](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/230)

````
documentclass: jss
author:
 - name: FirstName LastName
    affiliation: University/Company
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: \email{name@company.com}
    url: http://rstudio.com
 - name: Second Author
    affiliation: Affiliation
title:
  formatted: "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \\pkg{foo}"
  # If you use tex in the formatted title, also supply version without
  plain:     "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo"
  # For running headers, if needed
  short:     "\\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title"
abstract: >
  The abstract of the article.
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keywords, not capitalized, "\\proglang{Java}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Java]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{booktabs} 
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book: 
    base_format: rticles::jss_article
---

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  tidy = "formatR",
  tidy.opts = list(blank = FALSE, width.cutoff = 40)
)
```

## Example 4: Interval-Censored data with univariate Bayesian multivariate imputation

1. Executing R commands. Dollar signs are not needed. 
blah blah blah `r x$B`. 

1. A pretty table

```r 
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)))
knitr::kable(summary(fit)$coefficients,
             label = "demo-table",
  digits = 3, caption = " A CAPTION HERE ", format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE
)
```
demo table \@ref(tab:demo-table)
````